# trying to make a timer for python screenshots

Tags: python, loops, iteration, screenshot

I am trying to make a script that will take a screenshot every 30 seconds.

This is what I have now:

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global path
    if pressed:
        takeScreenshoot(path)
        print('ScreenShoot Taken')
```

---

What I have tried to do.

```
import time
while True: # Change for a variable or a toggle
       time.sleep(30)
       takeScreenshoot(path)
       print('ScreenShoot Taken')
```

however now because of this the next part of my code is unreache able

Comment: Use a while True loop, and just wait at the end.

Comment: Just wanted to tell you that there is no takeScreenshot() in python I don't if you have made it with pyautogui or some other package

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time
while True: # Change for a variable or a toggle
       time.sleep(30)
       takeScreenshoot(path)
       print('ScreenShoot Taken')
```

This might be something you could do,

Answer (score 0):

Well it is simple

```
import time
while True:
    takeScreenshot(path)
    time.sleep(30)
    print('screenshot taken')
```

This simple while code that runs forever will work if you want to break it after sometime you can use an index variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def f(x):
   while True:
    time.sleep(2.1)
    print(f'ScreenShoot Taken: {x}')


def g(x):
   for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2.2)
    print(f'Ho Ho Ho: {x}')


f = Thread(target=f, args=["bla"])
f.daemon = True
f.start()
g("bla")
```

In this example both functions work at the same time. You can of course replace g() with your code. If you do not set the thread to `daemon`, the program will not quit, because the thread function f() runs infinitely. If it is set to daemon, the thread will exit the moment the main code exits.